# Spring boot repository java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, repository

My spring boot application was working as well.

Then it doesn't work once changed to get Inputsteam instead of MultipartFile.

Previous Code here:

```
@Service
public class FileService {
@Autowired
Interface_freight_index interface_freight_index;
@Autowired
Interface_freight_chargecodes interface_freight_chargecodes;
@Autowired
Interface_billing_invoice_items interface_billing_invoice_items;
@Autowired
Interface_billing_invoice_header interface_billing_invoice_header;

public void save(MultipartFile file, boolean isCsv, boolean isXlsx) {

try {
  List<Object> FreightIndex = null;
  FreightIndex = ParseHelper.FileParser(file.getInputStream(), isCsv, isXlsx);

  for (Object row : FreightIndex) {
    if (row instanceof freight_index) interface_freight_index.saveAndFlush((freight_index) row);
    else if (row instanceof freight_chargecodes) interface_freight_chargecodes.saveAndFlush((freight_chargecodes) row);
    else if (row instanceof billing_invoice_items) interface_billing_invoice_items.saveAndFlush((billing_invoice_items) row);
    else if (row instanceof billing_invoice_header) interface_billing_invoice_header.saveAndFlush((billing_invoice_header) row);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("fail to store csv data: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Current Code here:

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class FileService {
@Autowired
private static Interface_freight_index interface_freight_index;
@Autowired
private static Interface_freight_chargecodes interface_freight_chargecodes;
@Autowired
private static Interface_billing_invoice_items interface_billing_invoice_items;
@Autowired
private static Interface_billing_invoice_header interface_billing_invoice_header;

public static void Save(InputStream file, boolean isCsv, boolean isXlsx) {

List<Object> FreightIndex = null;
FreightIndex = ParseHelper.FileParser(file, isCsv, isXlsx);

try {
  for (Object row : FreightIndex) {
    if (row instanceof freight_index) interface_freight_index.save((freight_index) row);
    else if (row instanceof freight_chargecodes) interface_freight_chargecodes.save((freight_chargecodes) row);
    else if (row instanceof billing_invoice_items) interface_billing_invoice_items.save((billing_invoice_items) row);
    else if (row instanceof billing_invoice_header) interface_billing_invoice_header.save((billing_invoice_header) row);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Here is the screenshot:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9zPj.png)

FileController codes here:

import com.pixeltrice.springbootimportcsvfileapp.services.FileService;

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")
@Controller
public class FileController {

public static void uploadFile(InputStream file, boolean isCsv, boolean isXlsx) {

try {
  FileService.Save(file, isCsv, isXlsx);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

row has the freight_index model format data.
but it looks null.

Help me.

Comment: It was just a question :). How do you use your FileService() class? Are you constructing an instance with the new operator or do you use it as a managed bean? Your `@Autowired` interfaces / classes are not injected.

Comment: here are FileController class codes:

 CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")
 Controller
 public class FileController {

 Autowired
  com.pixeltrice.springbootimportcsvfileapp.services.FileService fileService;


    public static void uploadFile(InputStream file, boolean isCsv, boolean isXlsx) {

     try {
      FileService.Save(file, isCsv, isXlsx);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }

Comment: Are the other @Autowired interfaces in your service also null ?

Comment: Ahhh... remove the `static` from the  interface fields. You can't use field injection on static fields. Have not seen that there is a static in front

Comment: yes, others also null
private static Interface_freight_index interface_freight_index;
  private static Interface_freight_chargecodes interface_freight_chargecodes;
  private static Interface_billing_invoice_items interface_billing_invoice_items;
  private static Interface_billing_invoice_header interface_billing_invoice_header;

Comment: Why can't u use your interfaces without `static`? You **can't** autowire static fields. Just with a workaround.

Comment: I can see this issue:
Non-static field 'interface_freight_index' cannot be referenced from a static context
once removed static from instance

Comment: remove the static from your method `save`

Comment: FIleController called the FileService
`FileService.Save(file, isCsv, isXlsx);`
`save` called by controller like above
so I can't remove the `static` from method `save`

Comment: herer are controller codes:

`@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")
@Controller
public class FileController {

  public void uploadFile(InputStream file, boolean isCsv, boolean isXlsx) {

    try {
      FileService.Save(file, isCsv, isXlsx);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Why is everything in your code `static`? Especially in your controller method? Currently it makes no sense to me. You Controller should have a dependency to your FileService as it is marked as @Service It will automatically generated and instantiated by the spring context. Then you can call the method of file service directly on the injected instance of file service

Comment: so how can I update my codes?

Comment: Remove all `static`s. In your controller class inject the FileService - we keep the field injection here so define a field in the controller class `@Autowired FileService fileService` and then invoke `fileService.Save` in your not static controller method. Why do you use static methods everywhere?

Comment: What have you done ?

Comment: I removed `fileservice.save()` from `main()` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all statics. In your controller class inject the `FileService` - we keep the field injection here so define a field in the controller class

```
@Autowired 
FileService fileService
```

and then invoke `fileService.Save` in your not static controller method.